# MVN with rotate arm instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, mov

This is a problem that came up on an exam but I can't understand the solution to it.

The ARM instruction is MVN R7, #0x8C, 4 and I have to find the value that is stored in R7.

The solution is as follows:

> = 0x8C ROR 4
>
> = (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 1100)<sub>2</sub> ROR 4
>
> = (1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000)<sub>2</sub>
>
> = 0xC0000008

This doesn't look right to me as MVN involves taking the complement and the above steps look like a simple MOV operation. Even if it is incorrect, what should be the right answer? Complement of penultimate step?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you're correct. The answer should be 0x3FFFFFF7.

Comment: when you executed it what did you get?

Comment: @RossRidge Thank you for confirming!

Comment: @dwelch Sorry but I don't know how to execute assembly programs on a computer. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can...

startup.s:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x20000
    bl notmain
hang: b hang

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl TEST
TEST:
    MVN R0,#0x8C,4
    bx lr
```

hello.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
unsigned int TEST ( void );
static void uart_putc ( unsigned int x )
{
    PUT32(0x101f1000,x);
}
static void bitstring ( unsigned int d )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    for(ra=0;ra<32;ra++)
    {
        if(d&0x80000000) uart_putc(0x31);
        else             uart_putc(0x30);
        d<<=1;
    }
    uart_putc(0x0D);
    uart_putc(0x0A);
}
int notmain ( void )
{
    bitstring(0x12345678);
    bitstring(TEST());
    return(0);
}
```

memmap:

```
MEMORY
{
    rom  : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
}
```

Makefile:

```
CROSS_COMPILE ?= arm-linux-gnueabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings 
COPS = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding 

hello_world.bin : startup.o hello.o memmap
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)-ld startup.o hello.o -T memmap -o hello_world.elf
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)-objdump -D hello_world.elf > hello_world.list
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)-objcopy hello_world.elf -O binary hello_world.bin

startup.o : startup.s
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)-as $(AOPS) startup.s -o startup.o

hello.o : hello.c 
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)-gcc -c $(COPS) hello.c -o hello.o

clean :
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.list
```

then

```
apt-get install qemu-system-arm binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
make
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel hello_world.bin
```

then press ctrl-alt-3 (3 not F3) to get the serial console.  where you will see your answer...

and closing that console window will exit qemu.

Or if you have a raspberry pi or a beaglebone or C.H.I.P or many other boards running linux or linux on arm in qemu or anywhere else.

test.s

```
.globl TEST
TEST:
    MVN R0,#0x8C,4
    bx lr
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern unsigned int TEST ( void );
int main ( void )
{
    printf("0x%08X\n",TEST());
    return(0);
}
```

and then

```
as test.s -o test.o
gcc main.c test.o -o main.elf
./main.elf
```

The bare metal route is pretty easy on those platforms.  Just have to actually init the uart, and wait for rx buffer to be empty, cant cheat like you can in a simulator.

Unfortunately you cant do this on a microcontroller since these days the are mostly cortex-m based

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.globl TEST
TEST:
    MVN R0,#0x8C,4
    bx lr
```

and that doesnt work

```
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:6: Error: unshifted register required -- `mvn R0,#0x8C,4'
```

If you have an ARM7TDMI based microcontroller (or other non-cortex-m) and have jtag, or even with the above with jtag you only have to feed it the one instruction. (can use gdb as well, even with qemu) feed the one instruction into memory somewhere

```
   1001c:   e3e0028c    mvn r0, #140, 4 ; 0xc0000008
```

so 0xe3e0028c is the r0 version of that instruction.  And step through it and then dump the registers you can see your answer as well.

You know gdb actually has or should have the armulator built into it or available so you might only need that.

the entire program:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    MVN R0,#0x8C,4
    b .
```

then
    arm-linux-gnueabi-ld test.s -o test.o
    arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -Ttext=0x8000 test.o -o test.elf

and get gdb

```
apt-get install gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

and then figure out how to load and run it in gdb, using the armulator, then stop it and dump the registers.

EDIT

Thanks for this question, I learned a few things...Links are bad, there are other pre-built toolchains, but as of this writing here is one

https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

and then get visualboyadvance.  these are supported on windows mac linux.

write this test.s program

```
.globl _start
_start:
    MVN R0,#0x8C,4
    b .
```

using that toolchain

```
arm-none-eabi-as test.s -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x02000000 test.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy test.elf -O binary  test.mb
```

In one window

```
vba -Gtcp test.mb
```

in another

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb
```

At the gdp prompt enter these three commands

```
target remote localhost:55555
si
info registers
```

and then you can use quit to exit out, it will exit vba as well, or did for me...

Comment: Just 7 easy steps! Except you left out a few things. Like installing Linux on his PC (if he has one) or school's computers (if doesn't). Oh, and you also left out an answer to his question.

Comment: hmm, I guess you cant apt-get gdb that way.

Comment: I did answer the question, how to find it.  If you dont have linux then it is trivial to boot a live linux on a usb or cdrom and then just follow the steps...can also run these tools on windows or mac.

Comment: found a number of simulators out there too.  could just hack out the lines of code for that instruction and run just that...

Comment: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded will get you a gdb, but it doesnt have the armulator in it.  but you can get visual boy advance and gdb into that...I assume...

Comment: Ross, I would rather teach them to fish than give them a fish for a question like this...

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I haven't yet read the complete answer but will definitely read it once I am done with the exams. By the way, I use ubuntu. :)